# Is there any way to send (embedded or otherwise) a vector image in an email signature

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, vector-graphics, email-signature

I am tired of how outlook (2012) butchers any images included in an email signature.

Whilst composing an email, I can use emf (vector based) which prints beautifully, etc..

When the send button is pressed, the image gets turned to a low quality jpeg.

Does outlook exchange support svg or emf as a 'linked image'?

Comment: While I'm thoroughly unfamiliar with the software you use and thus can't answer your question, I can inform you that I would be quite unhappy about it if everyone who sent me email attached a useless picture in their sigs.

Comment: Eroen, I'm glad you understand! You would prefer useful pictures attached to sigs!
Our organisations current sigs are ugly, and use more data than they should. I would like to change this!

Comment: I'm afraid you're stuck with JPEGs. There is no vector graphics format that is supported by all (or most) popular email clients. Whether or not you can send SWGs or EMFs is irrelevant, most of your email recipients will not see them.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Looks like Eroen will have to be happy with useless pixelated images attached to our email. :-)

Comment: Agreeing with @Eroen, I think what s/he means is that signature images are a pain, regardless of quality. I hate getting emails with signature images in them, so I have disabled load-images. A lot of people do this deliberately, and the resulting image-less email makes the sender look like a bit of a noob....  But if you absolutely must: keep it small, keep it neutral.

Answer (score 2):

You could use PNGs instead of JPEGs. If your logo has few colors, it may compress better and PNGs are lossless.